# Creating list in Pandas Dataframe at Index level using .apply() and Range function

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, range, apply

[image: Dataframe snapshot]

I am trying to create a list at every index level in my dataframe using the range function. The list should have a start value equal to '95_moneyness' and end value of '105_moneyness' with step value of 5. So for example, at Index = 1 the list should look like: [3095, 3100, 3105, 3110,...,3420]. So far I have tried the following code:

```
df2.apply(range(df2['95_moneyness'], df2['105_moneyness'], 5), axis=0)
```

And I receive the following error:

```
'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.
```

I imagine this is a result of my trying to pass a series to range and not an integer.

Can anybody recommend a solution? I thought about potentially defining my own custom range function for this or am open to completely different methods.

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you should try with `axis=1`. So, it should look like this: `df2.apply(range(df2['95_moneyness'], df2['105_moneyness'], 5), axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, however, this unfortunately gives the same error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is that you're using `df` instead of the row variable. Also, you need to change the axis to be `axis=1` in order to iterate over the rows. Finally, you need to cast the `float` values into `int`.

In short, the command should be like the following:

```
df.apply(lambda x: range(int(x['95_moneyness']), int(x['105_moneyness']), 5), axis=1)
```

And here it is a minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"95_moneyness": [3095.0, 3075.0, 3085.0, 3075.0, 3095.0],
                    "105_moneyness": [3420.0, 3395.0, 3410.0, 3400.0, 3415.0]})

df["new"] = df.apply(lambda x: range(int(x['95_moneyness']), int(x['105_moneyness']), 5), axis=1)
print(df)
#   95_moneyness  105_moneyness                                                new
#0        3095.0         3420.0  (3095, 3100, 3105, 3110, 3115, 3120, 3125, 313...
#1        3075.0         3395.0  (3075, 3080, 3085, 3090, 3095, 3100, 3105, 311...
#2        3085.0         3410.0  (3085, 3090, 3095, 3100, 3105, 3110, 3115, 312...
#3        3075.0         3400.0  (3075, 3080, 3085, 3090, 3095, 3100, 3105, 311...
#4        3095.0         3415.0  (3095, 3100, 3105, 3110, 3115, 3120, 3125, 313...
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the help, this seems to have done the trick! My dataframe now has a new column which is a range of values between the two moneyness levels. This prompts me to ask an additional followup question: can I store this new column as a list at every index level instead of a range object? I want to perform additional manipulation to these objects and I am not sure if storing them as a list or range object is better.

Comment: If you want to get a list, then you can simply cast the range object like so: `list(range(...))`. But they're both the same.